# semantic-ui - laying out fields in a form

Tags: semantic-ui

How can I make a layout like this using `.field` or other techniques?
I need field 5 to take up 2 field spaces.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at http://jsfiddle.net/3tzzj0de/1/ (you might need to expend the result box in order to disable the "small screen view"

the first row split into three equal fields:

```
<div class="three fields">
    <div class="field">...</div>
    <div class="field">...</div>
    <div class="field">...</div>
<div>
```

the second row use field sizing as a grid http://semantic-ui.com/collections/form.html#field-width

```
<div class="fields">
    <div class="six wide field">...</div>
    <div class="ten wide field">...</div>
</div>
```

so the 1 and 4 fields are not exactly aligned, i guess it would need to change the grid settings based on 15 columns (16 by default), and split to a 5 wide and a 10 wide fields.

Comment: Yep, I guess changing grid settings is the only viable option here. Thank you.